# Remove From Duplicate Starting Names From List Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of paths that look like 
//servername/d$/directory

I am getting the serverName from the path with the following

```
 var host = somePath.Split(new[] { '\\' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).FirstOrDefault();
```

I want to refine this list to only 1 server Name listed (say the first one found)

```
Example
if the list contains
//serverA/d$/directoryA
//serverA/d$/directoryB
//serverA/d$/directoryC
//serverB/d$/directoryD
//serverB/d$/directoryE

the list would turn into
//serverA/d$/directoryA
//serverB/d$/directoryD
```

Comment: [Please show what you've done](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can group them by the server name (by trimming the start and splitting on the `/` character and taking the first item), and then select the first item from each group into a new list:

```
var serverNames = new List<string>
{
    "//serverA/d$/directoryA",
    "//serverA/d$/directoryB",
    "//serverA/d$/directoryC",
    "//serverB/d$/directoryD",
    "//serverB/d$/directoryE",
};

var results = serverNames
    .GroupBy(name => name.TrimStart('/').Split('/')[0])
    .Select(group => group.First())
    .ToList();
```

From your first code example it's not clear if the paths begin with `\`, so to handle both cases you can do:

```
var results = serverNames
    .GroupBy(name => name.TrimStart('\\', '/', ' ').Split('\\', '/')[0])
    .Select(group => group.First())
    .ToList();
```